# Как добавить дефис к заглавным буквам

Tags: python

Допустим у меня есть строка, к примеру `'Hello World My Name Is John'`

Мне нужно преобразовать её во что то подобное `'hello-world-my-name-is-john`.

Я пробовал `string.replace(' ', '-').lower()`, но проблема в том, что строка может быть подобной этой `'HellloWorldMyNameIsJohn'`, и тогда программа не работает.

Comment: "Черточки" это дефис? "После заглавных букв" это перед заглавными буквами?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант решения через регулярные выражения.
Заменяем все заглавные буквы, кроме начальной, на дефис + строчную букву. Пробелы перед словами, начинающимися с заглавных букв, не захватываем, поэтому они удаляются. Для замены используется лямбда, которая возвращает дефис + захваченную группу, переведенную в нижний регистр.

```
text = 'Hello World My Name Is John HellloWorldMyNameIsJohn'
text = re.sub(r'(?<!^)\s*([A-ZА-ЯЁ])', lambda x: '-' + x[1].lower(), text)
print(text)
```

```
Hello-world-my-name-is-john-helllo-world-my-name-is-john
```

Answer (score 1):

Алгоритм в лоб: перебирать буквы по одной, если буква строчная, то присоединять ее к итоговой строке (в новой переменной), если же буква заглавна, то вместе с ней присоединить и дефис.

Comment: Как решить проблему с тем, что в начале добавляется черточка. То есть, к примеру строка 'MyGame' превращается в '-my-game', вместо 'my-game'.

Я учу питон всего несколько дней, поэтому заранее извиняюсь если задаю очень глупые вопросы

Comment: @romanzagadka используйте `s.strip("-")` это уберит дефис в начале и в конце. Чтобы убрать только с одной стороны можно использовать `lstrip` или `rstrip`